# Test equality of permutation which is not yet sorted

Tags: python, list, sorting

I need to test two permutations for equality, however they are still unsorted. Let's say I've got two list of tuples, i.e.

```
l1 = [(1, 15.0), (2, 13.0), (3, 17.0)]
l2 = [(1, 12.0), (2, 14.0), (3, 10.0)]
```

After sorting them according to the second element in each tuple, the lists would look like this:

```
l1 = [(2, 13.0), (1, 15.0), (3, 17.0)]
l2 = [(3, 10.0), (1, 12.0), (2, 14.0)]
```

No I would like to check equality of of the permutations given by the order of the first element in each tuple:

```
[2, 1, 3] == [3, 2, 1]
```

Is there a fast and easy way to skip the full sorting of both lists to improve performance? My current approach is to have a generator for each list that yields the next item according to the 2nd element and so I can instantly test for equality.

Comment: Should that be `[2, 1, 3] == [3, 1, 2]` ?

Comment: @hiroprotagonist I don't think that's what they want. I think their current *logic* is sound, maybe their *implementation* could be improved but we need to see the code for that

Comment: I don't think you can skip the sorting, but you may be able to speed up the permutation equality test by using a generator expression (or something involving `zip`) as the arg to `all`, which short-circuits as soon as an unequal pair of items is detected.

Comment: Can you show the code for current approach? Also numpy might help speed it up

Comment: @Chris_Rands Maybe, if the input lists are large &/or the input data can be read directly into Numpy arrays. Otherwise, if we're converting short Python lists of tuples to Numpy arrays the overhead may outweigh the speed benefits of Numpy.  OTOH, [`argsort`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html) is impressively fast...

Comment: @PM2Ring Yep agreed I do not know what would be best without benchmarking

Answer (score 0):

This is one `numpy` implementation utilizing [`numpy.argsort`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html). You can optimize further *within* `numpy` (use in-place operations), but performance may already be sufficient for your needs:

```
import numpy as np

l1 = [(1, 15.0), (2, 13.0), (3, 17.0)]
l2 = [(1, 12.0), (2, 14.0), (3, 10.0)]

a1 = np.array(l1)
a2 = np.array(l2)

res = (a1[a1[:,1].argsort()][:,0] == a2[a2[:,1].argsort()][:,0]).all()

# False
```